# How to draw arrows on a line-chart with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add an arrow to the end of my Highcharts line-chart. I've already looked through [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619240/arrow-of-line-chart-highcharts) but the solutions don't seem to work:

The result i'm looking for (added in colors),

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap the drawGraph method and add the code for arrow. It can be realised by path method.

```
(function(H) {
        H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

          // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
          // which are sliced off this function's arguments
          proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

          var arrowLength = 15,
            arrowWidth = 9,
            series = this,
            data = series.data,
            len = data.length,
            segments = data,
            lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
            path = [];


          var lastPoint = null;
          var nextLastPoint = null;

          if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
            lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
            nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
          } else {
            lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
            nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
          }

          var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
            (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

          if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

          path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

          if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {
            path.push(
              'L',
              lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
            );
            path.push(
              lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
            );
            path.push(
              lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
              'Z'
            );
          } else {
            path.push(
              'L',
              lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
            );
            path.push(
              lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
            );
            path.push(
              lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
              lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
              'Z'
            );
          }

          series.chart.renderer.path(path)
            .attr({
              fill: series.color
            })
            .add(series.group);

        });
      }(Highcharts));
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/

Comment: This seems to draw the arrow at the end of the line.
It is very helpful but would be more accurate (look how excel and the likes do it) if the arrow point was on the last data point being plotted.

Comment: I ran into a new problem; I'm using this Highcharts-arrow on a graph next to another Highcharts-graph (separated by navigation tabs) in the same ASP.NET webpage. All my JS files are being rendered together and in someway the arrow from one chart disappears if I update the data from the another chart (on the other tab). Have somebody an idea how can this be solved?

Comment: Since HC5, you can use defs and add arrows like here: http://jsfiddle.net/o8mnz5k8/

Answer (score 2):

**(UPDATE)**

The previous solution is not quite responsive because it redraws the arrow on the chart every single time when the browser is resized.

- Old Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/

However I found out how to make the chart with the arrow fully responsive:

```
(function(H) {

    var arrowCheck = false,
        pathTag;

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

    // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
    // which are sliced off this function's arguments

    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    var arrowLength = 15,
        arrowWidth = 9,
        series = this,
        data = series.data,
        len = data.length,
        segments = data,
        lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
        path = [],
        lastPoint = null,
        nextLastPoint = null;

    if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
       lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
       nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
    } else {
       lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
       nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
    }

    var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
        (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

    if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

    path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

    if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

       if (arrowCheck === true) {

         pathTag = document.getElementById("arrow");
         if (pathTag != null) {
           pathTag.remove(pathTag);
       }
     }

     path.push(
        'L',
        lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
        lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
     );
     path.push(
        lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
        lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
     );
     path.push(
        lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
        lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
        'Z'
     );
    } else {     

       if (arrowCheck === true) {

          pathTag = document.getElementById("arrow");
          if (pathTag != null) {
             pathTag.remove(pathTag);
          }
       }

       path.push(
         'L',
         lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
         lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
       );
       path.push(
         lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
         lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
       );
       path.push(
         lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
         lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
         'Z'
       );

    }

    series.chart.renderer.path(path)
    .attr({
       fill: series.color,
       id: 'arrow'
    })
    .add(series.group);

    arrowCheck = true;

   });
}(Highcharts));
```

- Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/3/

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: This doesn't work in IE 11 or below
You could change 
pathTag.remove(pathTag);
to 
pathTag.parentNode.removeChild(pathTag);

Answer (score 2):

Great help for me!

One note, the code above only works if there is only one series on the graph.  I made a few changes that lets it work with more than one series.  The issue was that since each arrow had the same ID, it would wipe out the prior arrows for other series, thinking they were old arrows that needed to be redrawn.  All I did was change the id to be a combo of 'arrow' and the series name, so it only wipes out the prior arrows for the specific series.

```
(function(H) {

    var arrowCheck = false,
        pathTag;

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

      // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

      // used a bit of regex to clean up the series name enough to be used as an id
      var arrowName = "arrow"+this.name.replace(/\W/g,"_").toLowerCase();
      // console.log("----------->arrowName:"+arrowName)

      var arrowLength = 15,
        arrowWidth = 7,
        series = this,
        data = series.data,
        len = data.length,
        segments = data,
        lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
        path = [],
        lastPoint = null,
        nextLastPoint = null;

      if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
        lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
        nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
      } else {
        lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
        nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
      }

      var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
        (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

      if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

      path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

      if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

        if (arrowCheck === true) {
          //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
          pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        );
      } else {


        if (arrowCheck === true) {
          //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
          pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        );
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        );
      }

      series.chart.renderer.path(path)
        .attr({
          fill: series.color,
          id: arrowName //changed from 'arrow' to arrowName to enable more than one series with an arrow
        })
        .add(series.group);

       arrowCheck = true;

    });
  }(Highcharts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Linted /cleaned up version of jmfeland's answer with two series

http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/18/

```
$(function() {

  (function(H) {
    var arrowCheck = false
    var pathTag

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {
      // Apply the original function with the original arguments,
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      var series = this
      proceed.apply(series, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))

      var arrowName = 'arrow' + series.name.replace(/\W/g, '_').toLowerCase()
      var arrowLength = 15
      var arrowWidth = 7
      var data = series.data
      var len = data.length
      var lastSeg = data[len - 1]
      var path = []
      var lastPoint = null
      var nextLastPoint = null

      if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
        lastPoint = data[len - 2]
        nextLastPoint = data[len - 1]
      } else {
        lastPoint = data[len - 1]
        nextLastPoint = data[len - 2]
      }

      var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
        (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY))

      if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle

      path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY)

      if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {
        if (arrowCheck === true) {
          pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName)
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag)
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        )
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        )
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        )
      } else {
        if (arrowCheck === true) {
          pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName)
          if (pathTag != null) {
            pathTag.remove(pathTag)
          }
        }

        path.push(
          'L',
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
        )
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
        )
        path.push(
          lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
          'Z'
        )
      }

      series.chart.renderer.path(path)
        .attr({
          fill: series.color,
          id: arrowName,
        })
        .add(series.group)

      arrowCheck = true
    })
  }(Highcharts))

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
      defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 10
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: {
          duration: 2000
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true,
          lineWidth: 2
        },
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'main',
      id: 'main',
      data: [
        [0, 0],
        [3, 4]
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'secondary',
      id: 'secondary',
      data: [
        [1, 0],
        [5, 8]
      ]
    }]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATE) plot graph XY

```
if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX || (lastPoint.plotX==nextLastPoint.plotX && lastPoint.plotY > nextLastPoint.plotY))
```

[Grap Arrow Line XY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc4h6.png)