# Highcharts connected mappoint with "direction"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I released an interactive map with Highcharts. 
It represents the path of an artist in 3 years in Italy.
It contains a serie with 3 points connected. 
How can I "print" arrows on the path to esplicate the "direction" of the path?

```
      {
          type: "mappoint",
          lineWidth: 2,
          data: [
              { lat: 41.108679365839755, lon: 16.849069442461108 },
              { lat: 40.65378710700787, lon: 14.759846388659303 },
              { lat: 41.90017321198485, lon: 12.16516614442158 }
          ]
      }
```

The full code is on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/0ghkmjpg/

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a method which is responsible for rendering line in the map and change the path so it shows an arrow between points. You can see the answer how to do it in a simple line chart [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392948/how-to-draw-arrows-on-a-line-chart-with-highcharts).

You can also use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path) directly and draw a path on load/redraw event.

Function for rendering path might look like this:

```
function renderArrow(chart, startPoint, stopPoint) {
  const triangle = function(x, y, w, h) {
    return [
      'M', x + w / 2, y,
      'L', x + w, y + h,
      x, y + h,
      'Z'
    ];
  };

  var arrow = chart.arrows[startPoint.options.id];

  if (!arrow) {
    arrow = chart.arrows[startPoint.options.id] = chart.renderer.path().add(startPoint.series.group);
  }

  const x1 = startPoint.plotX;
  const x2 = stopPoint.plotX;

  const y1 = startPoint.plotY;
  const y2 = stopPoint.plotY;

  const distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
  const h = Math.min(Math.max(distance / 3, 10), 30);
  const w = h / 1.5;

  if (distance > h * 2) {
    const offset = h / 2 / distance;
    const y = y1 + (0.5 + offset) * (y2 - y1);
    const x = x1 + (0.5 + offset) * (x2 - x1);

    const arrowPath = triangle(x - w / 2, y, w, h);
    const angle = Math.round(Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;

    arrow.attr({
      d: arrowPath.join(' '),
      transform: `rotate(${angle} ${x} ${y})`,
      fill: 'black',
      zIndex: 10,
      visibility: 'visible'
    });
  } else {
    arrow.attr({
      visibility: 'hidden'
    });
  }
}
```

And function which loops through the points and render arrows

```
function renderArrows() {
  if (!this.arrows) {
    this.arrows = {};
  }

  const points = this.series[1].points;
  points.reduce((start, stop) => {
    renderArrow(this, start, stop);
    return stop;
  });
}
```

Attach rendering arrows on load/redraw event

```
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

chart: {
  animation: false,
  events: {
    load: renderArrows,
    redraw: renderArrows
  }
},
```

Of course there is a lot of space in that question how the arrows should behave - should they have always constant size, when should they appear/disappear, exact shape and styles of the arrow, etc. - but you should be able to adjust the code above.

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/jq0oxtpw/

[image: arrow on map]