# Highcharts: arrow being rendered on the wrong charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I have 3 Highcharts charts on a webpage with a jQuery-UI tabs navigation system - one chart per tab. In *only* one of these charts I added an arrow to the plotted line. This arrow gets generated inside an IIFE (see the code sample below). Otherwise the 
Highcharts functions are pretty standard.

The problem occurs when I try to switch tabs and present the data for the other two charts: the arrow is being drawn on the charts that shouldn't have any arrows.

The erroneous arrow isn't *always* drawn on the other charts - never on the first render, and usually only after the user has switched tabs two or three times, then the arrow appears where it shouldn't. I also noticed that this IIFE is being called each time a chart is rendered (even from the other tabs).

I don't know how Highcharts works internally but each one of my charts is attached to a different DOM element (by ID), therefore Highcharts shouldn't mix the charts when the arrow is being rendered.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
      (function (H) {

            var arrowCheck = false, //This variable helps the arrow to be responsive
                pathTag;



            H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function (proceed) {

                // Now apply the original function with the original arguments,
                // which are sliced off this function's arguments
                // This section takes care of the arrow of the graph

                proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

                var arrowLength = 14,
                    arrowWidth = 7,
                    series = this,
                    data = series.data,
                    segments = data,
                    lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
                    path = [],
                    lastPoint = null,
                    nextLastPoint = null;

                if (typeof (lastSeg) === "undefined") {
                    return;
                }

                if (lastSeg.y === 0) {
                    lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
                    nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
                } else {
                    lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
                    nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
                }

                var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
                    (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

                if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;


                path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

                if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

                    if (arrowCheck === true) {

                        pathTag = doc.getElementById("arrow");
                        if (pathTag != null) {
                            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
                        }
                    }

                    path.push(
                        'L',
                        lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
                        lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
                    );
                    path.push(
                        lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
                        lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
                    );
                    path.push(
                        lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
                        lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
                        'Z'
                    );

                } else {

                    if (arrowCheck === true) {

                        pathTag = doc.getElementById("arrow");
                        if (pathTag != null) {
                            pathTag.remove(pathTag);
                        }
                    }

                    path.push(
                        lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
                    );
                    path.push(
                        lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
                        lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
                    );
                    path.push(
                        lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
                        lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
                        'Z'
                    );

                }

                series.chart.renderer.path(path)
                    .attr({
                        fill: series.color,
                        id: 'arrow'
                    })
                    .add(series.group);
                arrowCheck = true;

            });

        }(Highcharts));
```

Here a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28qfr7c5/) example (you just need to resize the section where the Charts are to see how the arrow jumps to the wrong chart)

Comment: You have wrapped the Highcharts code so you have changed its internal behaviour - the wrap applies to all the charts on your website. For sure it can be improved to do what you want but your code is not complete - read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you make a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle?

Comment: @morganfree Thank you for your suggestion. Here you can see a reduced example of the issue (https://jsfiddle.net/28qfr7c5/). You just need to resize the chart-section to see how the arrow jumps from one tab to the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell the problem is really two-fold:

1. The arrowhead code runs and displays on every chart
2. There is only one html element ID used for it, so it will remove that element on the previous chart draw and show it on the current.

So... when you first draw your charts, the arrow is added to the second chart. Then removed. Then added to the first chart (because that is the order you have them in the code).  So at this point you see the arrow on the first chart, and not on the second.

When HighCharts detects a resize is needed it redraws the charts. But internally the charts have a different order, so the first chart is drawn (this one you want to have an arrow), its arrow with `id="arrow"` is first removed, then it is re-added. Now the second chart redraw happens: it removes any arrows with `id="arrow"` (even though it now happens to be on another chart), and then adds it to its chart.  Now the arrow appears on chart 2.

So that's why it swaps from one to the other. What to do about it?

First, add a parameter to the chart's `plotOptions` if you want it to include an arrow in that particular chart. Note that you can do this on multiple charts:

```
...
plotOptions: {
  showArrow: true  // signals that this chart requires an arrow
},
...
```

Second, detect this setting and only process if it is present:

```
(function(H) {

    var arrowCheck = false,
      pathTag;

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

      // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

      if (this.chart.options.plotOptions.showArrow) {
        // used a bit of regex to clean up the series name enough to be used as an id
        var arrowName = "arrow" + this.name.replace(/\W/g, "_").toLowerCase();

        var arrowLength = 15,
          arrowWidth = 9,
          series = this,
          data = series.data,
          len = data.length,
          segments = data,
          lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
          path = [],
          lastPoint = null,
          nextLastPoint = null;

        if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
          lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
          nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
        } else {
          lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
          nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
        }

        var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
          (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

        if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

        path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

        if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

          if (arrowCheck === true) {
            //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
            pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
            if (pathTag != null) {
              pathTag.remove(pathTag);
            }
          }

          path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
          );
        } else {


          if (arrowCheck === true) {
            //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
            pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
            if (pathTag != null) {
              pathTag.remove(pathTag);
            }
          }

          path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
          );
        }

        series.chart.renderer.path(path)
          .attr({
            fill: series.color,
            id: arrowName //changed from 'arrow' to arrowName to enable more than one series with an arrow
          })
          .add(series.group);

        arrowCheck = true;

      }
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Finally, note that I've used the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925450/1544886 to make sure that each chart has a unique element ID for the arrowhead.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/4y86mwyk/