# How to draw arrows on a pie-chart with Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

[image]

> I am using a pie-chart of highchart and some settings are:-

```
 pie: {
          borderColor: '#000000',
          innerSize: '60%'
 },
 series: [{
          data: [
          ['projected Income', 44.2],
          ['Discount', 26.6],
          ['Annual Loss', 20]
     ]}]
 }
```

> Now my requirement is to **show the arrow on the Annual loss graph** as shown in picture of blue colour. Is it
>   possible to implement this in pie chart of Highcharts?
>   I have seen many
>   examples but those are explained for Line-Charts.

Comment: check this for line chart https://stackoverflow.com/q/38392948/8632727 but for pie chart how you want please add picture

Comment: @Patata I already mentioned that for Line chart graph many examples are their but for pie it is possible or not.

Comment: It is possible with the use of [renderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) object - it allows you to define any shape you need. If you have a picture of what you need, that would be helpful to create a poc for that.

Comment: @morganfree I added the picture. I need arrow as shown in blue graph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For line/scatter/bars you could use [annotations](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module) but they are not available for pie/donut charts.

So using [SVGRenderer](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer.html) you can add extra SVG elements to your pie/donut chart.

In my example below I draw a line using an SVG marker as arrow:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: "My Title"
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      borderColor: '#000000',
      innerSize: '60%',
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.1f}',
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      ['projected Income', 44.2],
      ['Discount', 26.6],
      ['Annual Loss', 20]
    ]
  }]
}, function(chart) {
  var point = chart.series[0].data[2];
  var dx = chart.plotBox.x,
    dy = chart.plotBox.y;
  var radius = point.shapeArgs.r;
  var angle = (point.shapeArgs.start + point.shapeArgs.end) / 2,
    x = (radius * .9 * Math.cos(angle)) + point.shapeArgs.x,
    y = (radius * .9 * Math.sin(angle)) + point.shapeArgs.y;
  var x2 = (radius * 1.5 * Math.cos(angle)) + point.shapeArgs.x,
    y2 = (radius * 1.5 * Math.sin(angle)) + point.shapeArgs.y;

  var text = chart.renderer.text(
      'Annual Loss',
      x2 + dx, y2 + dy
    ).attr({
      zIndex: 5
    }).add(),
    box = text.getBBox();
  text.attr({
    dx: -box.width / 2
  });

  chart.renderer.rect(box.x - 5 - box.width / 2, box.y - 5, box.width + 10, box.height + 10, 5).attr({
    fill: '#FFFFEF',
    'stroke': 'red',
    'stroke-width': 1,
    zIndex: 4
  }).add();

  console.log(point, chart);

  chart.renderer.path({
    'stroke': '#ff0000',
    'stroke-width': 3,
    'marker-end': "url(#markerArrow2)",
    zIndex: 3,
    'd': ['M', x2 + dx, y2 + dy, 'L', x + dx, y + dy]
  }).add();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<svg style="height: 0">
  <defs>
     <marker id="markerArrow" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" refX="2" refY="6"
           orient="auto">
        <path d="M2,2 L2,11 L10,6 L2,2 Z" style="fill: red;" />    
    </marker> 
    
     <marker id="markerArrow2" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="6" refY="6"
           orient="auto">
        <path d="M2,2 L10,6 L2,10 L6,6 L2,2 Z" style="fill: red;" />    
    </marker> 
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Here is the link to a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/k091v22e/